# how to restrict user to input only upto two decimal point float numbers in python?

Tags: python

I am new in python, i want to do is limit the float input by the user only upto two decimal point, eg: 1.11, user is not allowed to input 1.111 or more than to after two decimal point . Thank you

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: volumeSelected = input("Please input the volume (in liters): ")

Comment: i want to limit input to only two decimal point . I got no idea

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted. The [edit] button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: You cannot limit what they `input()` but you can validate and reject any non-conformant inputs. Note: you should use the `decimal.Decimal` type, as this will provide an exact representation of decimals, vs. the rounding challenges you get with the `float` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restrict what the user inputs, but you can convert a float to have 2 decimal points:

```
value = float(input("Input your number: "))
print ("You inputted " + str(value))
new_value = "{:.2f}".format(value)
print ("After formatting, your number has become: " + str(new_value))
```

Comment: It is against the ethos of StackOverflow to answer a question like this where the person asking the question hasn't even tried. You should insist on the question including code that has been tried before answering.

Comment: Emm so do I delete this answer? I won't do it next time though

Comment: Yes, you should delete this answer.